# iterator to pointer or reference - ERROR

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, libstdc++

I have this:

```
//function definition
//Point and Range are classes made of 2 ints
Point barycenter_of_vector_in_range(vector<cv::Point> &points, cv::Range range);

//In other place...
vector<vector<Point> > tracks_; //it has some content 
for (vector< vector<Point> >::const_iterator track = tracks_.begin(); track != tracks_.end(); track++) {

    Point barycenter = barycenter_of_vector_in_range(&(*track), Range(0, track->size())); //Compile ERROR
}
```

I wonder why this is not working? I get "Invalid initialization of referenceof type ..."

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*track` is a reference to `const vector<Point>`, so you have two problems:

1) You're trying to pass a pointer to that into `barycenter_of_vector_in_range`, which doesn't take a pointer.

2) It's `const`, and `barycenter_of_vector_in_range` takes a non-const reference.

Comment: +1 I was just about to hit `post` with pretty much the same answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made function to accept const and *points rather than &points ;)

Comment: @nacho4d: or the function could take a const reference, and you could pass it `*track`.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a pointer to a vector of points instead of the vector itself (of which the compiler implicitely takes the reference)